# carrierwave not creating method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I am trying to add an image upload to a form through carrierwave and that displaying the picture through an image tag.

Therefore I generated a Picture Uploader and a migration

```
$ rails generate uploader Picture
$ rails generate migration add_picture_to_cpostings picture:string
```

and migrated.

I also added

```
mount_uploader :picture, PictureUploader
```

to the cpostings model.

In the controller I permitted the picture attribute

```
def cposting_params
    params.require(:cposting).permit(:content, :spots, :class_date, :class_time, :title, :picture)
end
```

The upload with

```
  <%= f.file_field :picture, accept: 'image/jpeg,image/gif,image/png' %>
```

in the form works, but when I try to display the picture in the posting with

```
<%= image_tag cposting.picture.url if cposting.picture? %>
```

I get the following error:

> undefined local variable or method `cposting' for #<#:0x007f9629cc76f0>

According to railstutorial.org, the method should be created automatically by carrierwave. Do you have any idea why it doesn't work here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
undefined local variable or method `cposting' for #<#:0x007f9629cc76f0>
```

From the error message it's clear that, your view does not find the `cposting` variable. You have to declare this `cposting` variable inside the corresponding controller's action as an instance variable (`@cposting`) and then it will be available in your view file and you will not get this error.

#### Update

Change:

```
<%= image_tag cposting.picture.url if cposting.picture? %>
```

To:

```
<%= image_tag @cposting.picture.url if @cposting.picture? %>
```

Comment: there's other things generated in the view like this:
<h1><%= @cposting.title %></h1>

and it works, therefore I think the problem isn't with cposting in the controller

Comment: Yes, because you have a `@` sing here: `@cposting.title` so it works.
But you are getting error, you only habe: `cposting` but NOT `@cposting`. Change that to `@cposting` and see if it works.

Comment: nevermind, I forgot the @ in the cposting.picture? boolean, now it works. thanks a lot mate

Comment: @moneymakesadifference glad that it helped you and its working for you. Please accept my answer as it helped you. To see how the accepting answers work, see here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work
Thanks.